# catkin_make multiple names

Tags: ros, catkin-make, multiple, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Lately I have been trying to use the `catkin_make` command, with no luck. It seems some of the packages in the stacks folder have been given the same name, and so I cannot compile correctly. Now, I can't remove these, as they are shared with some co-workers, and I do not know if they are using them. So, is there some other choice for me to be able to compile on my catkin_workspace?

This is the message from `catkin_make`:

```
/opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/em/order_packages.cmake.em:23:
error: <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: Multiple packages found with the same name
"camera_calibration_parsers":
- share/camera_calibration_parsers
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers
- stacks/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers
Multiple packages found with the same name "camera_info_manager":
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/camera_info_manager
- stacks/image_common/camera_info_manager
Multiple packages found with the same
name "image_common":
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/image_common
- stacks/image_common/image_common Multiple packages found with the same
name "image_transport":
- share/image_transport
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/image_transport
- stacks/image_common/image_transport Multiple packages found with the same
name "polled_camera":
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/polled_camera
- stacks/image_common/polled_camera Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/empy", line 3288, in
<module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': main()   File "/usr/bin/empy", line 3286, in
main
    invoke(sys.argv[1:])   File "/usr/bin/empy", line 3269, in invoke
    interpreter.wrap(interpreter.file, (file, name))   File "/usr/bin/empy",
line 2273, in wrap
    self.fail(e)   File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2264, in wrap
    apply(callable, args)   File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2337, in file
    self.safe(scanner, done, locals)   File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2379, in
safe
    self.parse(scanner, locals)   File "/usr/bin/empy", line 2399, in parse
    token.run(self, locals)   File "/usr/bin/empy", line 1410, in run
    interpreter.execute(self.code, locals)   File "/usr/bin/empy", line
2576, in execute
    exec statements in self.globals   File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/topological_order.py",
line 111, in topological_order for path, package in find_packages(space).items():   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/packages.py",
line 92, in find_packages
    raise RuntimeError('\n'.join(duplicates))
RuntimeError: Multiple packages found with the same name
"camera_calibration_parsers":
- share/camera_calibration_parsers
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers
- stacks/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers
Multiple packages found with the same name "camera_info_manager":
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/camera_info_manager
- stacks/image_common/camera_info_manager
Multiple packages found with the same name "image_common":
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/image_common
- stacks/image_common/image_common Multiple packages found with the same name "image_transport":
- share/image_transport
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/image_transport
- stacks/image_common/image_transport Multiple packages found with the same name "polled_camera":
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/polled_camera
- stacks/image_common/polled_camera
```

Using ROS Groovy and Ubuntu 12.10.

Thanks for your attention.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197361/catkin_make-multiple-names/) by [hiro64](https://answers.ros.org/users/20213/hiro64/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-11-13**:
Please edit your original question if you are going to add any new information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have several packages with same name in different places on your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` and/or in your workspace:

```
RuntimeError: Multiple packages found with the same name
"camera_calibration_parsers":
- share/camera_calibration_parsers
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers
- stacks/image_common/camera_calibration_parsers
Multiple packages found with the same name "camera_info_manager":
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/camera_info_manager
- stacks/image_common/camera_info_manager
Multiple packages found with the same name "image_common":
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/image_common
- stacks/image_common/image_common Multiple packages found with the same name "image_transport":
- share/image_transport
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/image_transport
- stacks/image_common/image_transport Multiple packages found with the same name "polled_camera":
- stacks/bumblebee2/image_common/polled_camera
- stacks/image_common/polled_camera
```

For example, as you can see above, you have the `camera_calibration_parsers` package in three locations.

It is not clear to me how you got to this point. We would need to know what is in your environment and exactly how you are building (command by command) your packages to understand how you might be going wrong.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1